# ng-bind but store internal value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Some server side code (GSP) is generating HTML for me like so:

```
<span>
    <g:generateAmount />
</span>
```

I'm wrapping this in a Angular controller and want to be able to bind a scope variable to the `span`:

```
<span ng-bind="subtotal">
    <g:generateAmount />
</span>
```

Problem is, after binding, the inner text is removed because subtotal isn't set in the controller on initialization (although writing to it from the controller works fine). `ng-model` doesn't seem to read it either.

**Question**

Is there a way to bind to a node but persist the data inside that node? For instance, in the above example, $scope.subtotal would be equal to whatever `<g:generateAmount />` outputs. I would then be able to update `subtotal` from the controller and have those changes reflected.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/robcampo/zg6GE/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create custom directive and get value from DOM before `$compile`.

Alternatively you can change your generated html and put `<g:generateAmount />` into [`ng-init`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) attribute, like

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="subtotal=<g:generateAmount>">
    <span ng-bind="subtotal" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! ng-init was thought of but I thought there may be a built-in directive approach. What if the <g:generateAmount/> above contains HTML, is there any safe way to wrap in inside the ng-init expression?

Comment: @RobCampo It can be tricky, you need to escape html entities so html would be valid, and use `ng-init="subtotal='<g:generateAmount>'">` for string value.